# Submit auto form without submit button

Tags: php

I want to auto submit form after 5 minutes without submit button my code is working but not get post value.Please help me.

```
<form name="addcontact" method="post"  content="2;" action="URL=demo.php">

<input type="text" name="addontable" value="Add on Table" />

</form>
```

Comment: Does `action` really have a value `URL=demo.php`?

Comment: Exactly, it should be without the URL= part, only demo.php if it even exists.

Comment: You should provide your javascript code also. How are you doing auto submission?

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong value for `action` attribute of the form - change it to:

```
<form name="addcontact" method="post"  content="2;" action="demo.php" content="2;">
    <input type="text" name="addontable" value="Add on Table" />
</form>
```